# Pointplot and Scatterplot in one figure but X axis is shifting

Tags: python, seaborn

Hi I'm trying to plot a pointplot and scatterplot on one graph with the same dataset so I can see the individual points that make up the pointplot.

Here is the code I am using:

```
xlPath = r'path to data here'

df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xlPath, sheet_name=None),ignore_index=True)

sns.pointplot(data=df, x='ID', y='HM (N/mm2)', palette='bright', capsize=0.15, alpha=0.5, ci=95, join=True, hue='Layer')
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='ID', y='HM (N/mm2)')

plt.show()
```

When I plot, for some reason the points from the scatterplot are offsetting one ID spot right on the x-axis. When I plot the scatter or the point plot separately, they each are in the correct ID spot. Why would plotting them on the same plot cause the scatterplot to offset one right?

[image]

Edit: Tried to make the ID column categorical, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @JohanC Hmm, I tried, but to no avial. What's weird is when I do the pointplot by itself or the scatter by itself, it plots correctly with no offset. Regardless of explicitly making the column categorical or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn's `pointplot` creates a categorical x-axis while here the `scatterplot` uses a numerical x-axis.

Explicitly making the x-values categorical: `df['ID'] = pd.Categorical(df['ID'])`, isn't sufficient, as the scatterplot still sees numbers.  Changing the values to strings does the trick. To get them in the correct order, sorting might be necessary.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first create some test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 49), 500),
                   'HM (N/mm2)': np.random.uniform(1, 10, 500)})
df['Layer'] = ((df['ID'] - 1) // 6) % 4 + 1
df['HM (N/mm2)'] += df['Layer'] * 8
df['Layer'] = df['Layer'].map(lambda s: f'Layer {s}')

# sort the values and convert the 'ID's to strings
df = df.sort_values('ID')
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
sns.pointplot(data=df, x='ID', y='HM (N/mm2)', palette='bright',
              capsize=0.15, alpha=0.5, ci=95, join=True, hue='Layer', ax=ax)
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='ID', y='HM (N/mm2)', color='purple', ax=ax)
ax.margins(x=0.02)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: combining sns.pointplot and sns.scatterplot]

Comment: that worked. Thank you!!